# To check contacts to see if the app is installed or not - Windows 8 phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows

Just need information for my understanding i.e. I'm designing an Windows 8 chat app and want the app to be intelligent to check if contact already got app installed or not like whatsApp and Viber which shows you the whatsApp icon indicating that person in your contact list is available on whatsApp/viber.

Really appreciate your help

Ta
Shoaib

Comment: User A signs up with their email.  User B checks to see if their contacts are members. Contact list goes to server. Contact A's email matches.  Chaching.

Answer (score 0):

- When user X register using your app, you need to pass his email / contact on server.
- Another user Y can check whether  his contacts are members  or not.
- You need to store some contact lists on server for particular user.